# Transferring XFCE customization from one system to another?

Tags: configuration, xfce, desktop-environment

I configured XFCE on my desktop at home and wanted to setup my work system with the same configurations (figured it'd just be copying a few files) or even a script? In the past I used to just mark the changes on paper and have to repeat myself with what ever desktop env I used.

Is there an easier way to replicate personalization changes from one system to the next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, the simplest way to transfer environment settings is to copy the user configuration directories wholesale, renaming the existing directories first. In the case of XFCE, that would be `~/.config/xfce4`. There may also be necessary files in `~/.local`. Be sure to install any requisite software before copying the configuration.